# Is this already a string similarity algorithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, string-comparison, similarity, sentence-similarity

I'm unfamiliar with string similarity algorithms except for Levenshtein Distance because that's what I'm using and it has turned out to be less than ideal.

So I've kind of got an idea of a recursive algorithm I'd like to implement but I want to know if it exists already so I can leverage other's expertise.

Here's the algorithm by example:

> string 1: "Paul Johnson"
>
> string 2: "John Paulson"

Step 1: find all longest matches

> Match 1: "Paul"
>
> Match 2: "John"
>
> Match 3: "son"
>
> Match 4: " "

Step 2: Calculate scores for each match with this formula: ((match.len/string.len)*match.len) This allows longer strings to be weighted more at a balanced rate based on the length of the string.

> Match 1: (4/12)*4 = 1.333...
>
> Match 2: 1.333...
>
> Match 3: .75
>
> Match 4: .083

Step 3: do steps 1 and 2 on larger scales, (matches of matches.) This I don't have figured out exactly. but my thinking is if "son" comes after "Paul John" and it comes after "John Paul" then that should count for something.

Step 4: sum all the scores that have been calculated.

> Scores: 1.333 + 1.333 + .75 + .083333 = 3.4999... (plus whatever scores step 3 produces)

Does this look familiar to anyone? I hope someone else has gone to the trouble of actually making an algorithm along these lines so I don't have to figure it out myself.

Comment: can you describe why Levenshtein distance is not ideal?

Comment: Are you only matching people names, or are you matching more general strings?

Comment: @Chris, in some cases, a local similarity might be more desirable than a global dissimilarity. This kind of alignment in two sequences is called the Local Sequence Alignment wherein you are more interested in finding the substrings of two strings that have maximum similarity.

Comment: @Chris I'm comparing sentences of variable length. example: which of these two sentences is "closer"  to the first one: 1. I love. 2. I love everyone. 3. hello. Well #3 is scored closer to #1 than #2 because its lengths are similar so the edit distance is short. even with the same lengths edit distance ignores how many letters are "next to each other" though it somewhat quantifies if their in the right order I think. anyway even though #2 and #1 has matching strings #3 has a lower edit distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe somewhat resembles what the following paper calls the Longest Common Substring (LCS). For a brief description and comparison to other algorithms:
[A Comparison of Personal Name Matching](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7EPeter.Christen/publications/tr-cs-06-02.pdf)

> This algorithm [11] repeatedly finds and removes the longest common
> sub-string in the two strings compared, up to a minimum lengths
> (normally set to 2 or 3).
>
> ...
> A similarity measure can be calculated by
> dividing the total length of the common sub-strings by the minimum,
> maximum or average lengths of the two original strings (similar to
> Smith-Waterman).
>
> ...
>
> this algorithm is
> suitable for compound names that have words (like given- and surname)
> swapped.

Comment: You should read the paper I linked to, and follow the example. It's unfortunate that he called it LCS, because it confuses it with the longest common substring problem, and longest common subsequence, both of which are different than what he's describing in the paper. What he describes would not match at all the example you gave in the comment above.

Comment: thanks, yes I noticed it gets confused with subsequence as I've been researching. I'll take a look in the meantime I've coded something close to (and more simple than) what I described above. I made a better explanation of what I coded exactly for my purposes here: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/9236#9236